# En una calculadora tengo un boton = y quiero que despues de presionarlo y se haga click en otro boton de numeros borre el resultado y agregue el nuevo

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs, reactjs, dom

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
```

***Estos son mis estados***

```
  const [displayer, setDisplayer] = useState("0");
  const [resolve, setResolve] = useState([]);
  const [operacionRealizada, setOperacionRealizada] = useState(false);
```

***Esta es mi funcion handleNumber la cual es para cuando se hace click en una tecla agregue ese numero al displayer y al resolve***

```
  const handleNumber = (e) => {
    const value = parseInt(e.target.value);
    const func = e.target.id;
    const lastChar = displayer[displayer.length - 1];
```

**Justo esta parte del codigo me deberia funcionar para que cuando operacionRealizada sea true borre el estado del resultado para asignar el nuevo numero presionado, pero no funciona por algun motivo que desconozco...**

```
    if (operacionRealizada) {
      // Si se realizó una operación anteriormente, resetea el estado
      setDisplayer(value.toString());
      setResolve([]);
      setOperacionRealizada(false);
    } else {
      // Si no se ha realizado una operación anteriormente, agrega el número al estado actual
      setDisplayer(displayer + value.toString());
    }
```

```
    setResolve(resolve + value);

    if (displayer[0] === "0") {
      setDisplayer(value.toString());
    } else if (
      lastChar === "/" ||
      lastChar == "X" ||
      lastChar == "-" ||
      lastChar == "+" ||
      lastChar == "."
    ) {
      setDisplayer(displayer.slice(0, -1) + value.toString());
    } else {
      setDisplayer(displayer + value.toString());
    }

    if (func === "AC") {
      setDisplayer("0");
      setResolve([]);
    }

    if (func === "divide") {
      if (
        lastChar === "/" ||
        lastChar == "X" ||
        lastChar == "-" ||
        lastChar == "+"
      ) {
        // Reemplaza el último carácter '-' con '/'
        setDisplayer(displayer.slice(0, -1) + "/");
        setResolve(resolve.slice(0, -1) + "/");
      } else if (lastChar !== "/") {
        setDisplayer("/");
        setResolve(resolve + "/");
      } else if (lastChar === "/") {
        setDisplayer(displayer);
        setResolve(resolve);
      }
    }

  const handleEqual = (list) => {
    let newArr = [];

    const numeroRegex = /[0-9]/; // Expresión regular para dígitos del 0 al 9
    let numeroActual = "";
    let resultado = [];
    let oper = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (numeroRegex.test(list[i])) {
        // Si es un dígito, agrega al número actual
        numeroActual += list[i];
      } else {
        // Si no es un dígito, agrega el número actual (si hay alguno) y el carácter actual
        if (numeroActual) {
          newArr.push(numeroActual);
          numeroActual = ""; // Reinicia el número actual
        }
        newArr.push(list[i]);
      }
    }

    // Agrega el número final (si hay alguno)
    if (numeroActual) {
      newArr.push(numeroActual);
    }

    for (let num of newArr) {
      if (numeroRegex.test(num)) {
        const numero = parseFloat(num);

        if (oper === null) {
          // Si no hay operación pendiente, establece el resultado como el primer número
          resultado.push(numero);
        } else {
          // Realiza la operación pendiente con el número y actualiza el resultado

          if (oper === "+") {
            resultado[resultado.length - 1] += numero;
          } else if (oper === "-") {
            resultado[resultado.length - 1] -= numero;
          } else if (oper === "X") {
            resultado[resultado.length - 1] *= numero;
          } else if (oper === "/") {
            resultado[resultado.length - 1] /= numero;
          }
          oper = null; // Restablece la operación pendiente
        }
      } else {
        // Si el elemento es un signo de operación, guárdalo como operación pendiente
        oper = num;
      }
    }

    if (resultado[0]) {
      setDisplayer(resultado[0].toString());
      setResolve("= " + resultado[0]);
    }
```

En esta parte una vez se pulsa = se cambia el estado a true para detectar que ya se pulso y asi manipular para cuando se pulse un nuevo numero se resetee el estado que ya habia, para mostrar ese nuevo nuemero que se ingreso, pero no se como hacerlo..

```
    setOperacionRealizada(true)
```